# is there match phrase any query in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

In elasticsearch `match_phrase` query will match full phrase.
`match_phrase_prefix` query will match phrase as prefix.
for example:

```
"my_field": "confidence ab"
```

will match: "confidence above" and "confidence about".

is there query for "match phrase any" like below example:

```
"my_field": "dence ab"
```

should fetch match: "confidence above" and "confidence about"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways that you can do this

1. Store the field values as-is in ES by applying [keyword analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html) type in mapping => Do a [wildcard search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html)
   (OR)
2. Store the field using [ngram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) => Do search your data based on your requirement with or without using [standard or keyword search analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html)

usually wildcard search are performance inefficient .

Please do let me know on your progress based on my above suggestions so that I can help you further if needed

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the mapping of your field to keyword like below:

```
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name":{
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then search over this field using wildcard like below:

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "name": {
        "value": "*dence ab*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please let me know if your have any problem with this.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the simplest solution is using [Query string query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) or [Simple query string query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html). The latter one is less strict with the query syntax error.

First, make sure that your field is mapped with type [`text`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html). The example below create a mapping for field named `my_field` under the `test-index`.

```json
{
  "test-index" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "my_field" : {
          "type" : "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, for searching, use query string query with wild-cards.

```json
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": ["my_field"], 
      "query": "*dence ab*"
    }
  }
}
```